# How to get the spinner value not in integer but in character

Tags: java, android

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

int noc = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String text= spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Coffee_names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position) + " is selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

My app stops when i add  " String text= spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); " to my code but it works fine when i remove this line from the program. But when i select a item from dropdown list it says 4 is selected. 
I want it to say the name of the item i selected and not the index value. 
Please help.

Comment: And what does it say in your logcat? I'm going to guess you've got a `NullPointerException` in there.

Comment: The problem is that in your code are trying get a selected item before that you add the adapter

Comment: spinner.getSelectedItem() is null, because there is no selected item at this stage. So you cannot "toString() it. "Eternal September" ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions..!!
I changed parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)    to  parent.getSelectedItem()    and then it showed the names in the list other than values..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getSelectedItem() + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative way**

```
final String[] coffeeNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Coffee_names);
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coffeeNames));
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedCoffeeName = coffeeNames[position];
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selectedCoffeeName + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```